# Using PicklingTools with QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt, pickle

I'm trying to use the latest version of PicklingTools (http://www.picklingtools.com/) with QT Creator. I just want to open a pickled sample file that I downloaded together with the PicklingTools files. So my main.cpp file looks very basic:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "chooseser.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Val result;
    LoadValFromFile("../PicklingTools163Release/C++/SamplePickles/p7.pkl",result,SERIALIZE_P0);
    return 0;
}
```

I edited the .pro file in the following way:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp \

INCLUDEPATH += ../PicklingTools163Release/C++/
INCLUDEPATH += ../PicklingTools163Release/C++/opencontainers_1_8_4/include/

LIBS += -pthread

HEADERS += \
    ../PicklingTools163Release/C++/chooseser.h \

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x -pthread
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fno-strict-aliasing -DLINUX_ -DOC_NEW_STYLE_INCLUDES -Wno-deprecated -I../PicklingTools163Release/C++/opencontainers_1_8_4/include -I../PicklingTools163Release/C++ -pthread -D_REENTRANT
```

At the moment I receive multiple undefined reference errors:

```
 - Fehler: undefined reference to `OC::CopyPrintableBufferToVector(char const*, unsigned long, char*, unsigned long)'
 - Fehler: undefined reference to `OC::P2TopLevelLoadVal(OC::Val&, char*)'
 - Fehler: undefined reference to `OC::OpalLoadSomeTable(OC::Val&, char*, bool, OC::MachineRep_e)'
 - Fehler: undefined reference to `OC::CopyPrintableBufferToVector(char const*, unsigned long, char*, unsigned long)'
 - Fehler: undefined reference to `OC::MakeVector(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long)'
```

I guess that I need to edit the `.pro` file further but right now I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The OpenContainers code works as INCLUDE ONLY, i.e., you don't have to link against anything to use JUST the OpenContainers code (OC::Val, OC::Tab, etc.).  BUT!

To use any of the Pickling code (like the undefined entries you see for `P2TopLevelLoadVal`, `MakeVector`, etc.) you need to build and link against the ptools library.  That library contains all the Python pickling code.

```
% cd /home/me/PicklingTools163Release/C++
% make -f Makefile.Linux libptools.so
# .... builds a lot of files, and put them into libptools.so ....
# Update your Makefile to link against libptools.so
```

Hope that helps.   Link against `libptools.so` in your Makefile.

Comment: I was looking exactly for this! Thank you